# MQL4 Indicator passing signal to EA

Tags: indicator, metatrader4, mql4

the problem is, I want to open order when my indicator gives signal. How can I do that?

I have been trying to do with **`iCustom()`** but it is not satisfying.

I tried to use **`GlobalVariableSet()`** in indicator and **`GlobalVariableGet()`** method in EA but it is not properly worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax](http://docs.mql4.com/indicators/icustom) is:

```
double  iCustom(
   string       symbol,           // symbol
   int          timeframe,        // timeframe
   string       name,             // path/name of the custom indicator compiled program
   ...                            // custom indicator input parameters (if necessary)
   int          mode,             // line index
   int          shift             // shift
   );
```

Here is the example using custom Alligator indicator (which should be available by default as `Alligator.mq4` in MT platform).

```
double Alligator[3];
Alligator[0] = iCustom(NULL, 0, "Alligator", 13, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0);
Alligator[1] = iCustom(NULL, 0, "Alligator", 13, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3, 1, 0);
Alligator[2] = iCustom(NULL, 0, "Alligator", 13, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3, 2, 0);
```

where `13, 8, 8, 5, 5, 3` are corresponding input parameters of custom Alligator as defined in indicator it-self:

```
//---- input parameters
input int InpJawsPeriod=13; // Jaws Period
input int InpJawsShift=8;   // Jaws Shift
input int InpTeethPeriod=8; // Teeth Period
input int InpTeethShift=5;  // Teeth Shift
input int InpLipsPeriod=5;  // Lips Period
input int InpLipsShift=3;   // Lips Shift
```

and `mode` is the corresponding line index as defined in the indicator by:

```
SetIndexBuffer(0, ExtBlueBuffer);
SetIndexBuffer(1, ExtRedBuffer);
SetIndexBuffer(2, ExtLimeBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
int signal = iCustom(NULL, 0, "MyCustomIndicatorName",
...parameters it takes in...,
...the buffer index you want from the custom indicator...,
...shift in bars);
```

Let's say you wrote a custom moving average indicator called "myMA" and it takes in a period only as one of its extern variables. This indicator calculates a simple moving average based on the period that the user supplies and on the close of each bar. This indicator stores its calculated values in an array `MAValues[]` that gets assigned to an index like this: `SetIndexBuffer(0, MAValues);`

To get the moving average of the current bar with period 200 then, you would write:

```
double ma_current_bar = iCustom(NULL, 0, "myMA", 200, 0, 0);
```

Then once you have this value you can check it against some trading criteria you determine, and open an order when it is met. For example if you wanted to open a long position if the moving average of the current bar equals the current Ask price, you would write:

```
if (ma_current_bar == Ask){
    OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, 1, Ask, *max slippage*, *sl*, *tp*, NULL, 0, 0, GREEN);
}
```

This is just example code, do NOT use this in a live EA.